# moving towards jpql query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the below method which is representing two different tables and that are connected with a common column `domain_id` , what my point of view is that instead of going through below approach can't I write the JPQL to achieve the same thing

```
@Override
public List<SrityDTO> getByCommonColumn(int id) throws Exception {
    Optional<main> ntOptional = ntRepository.findById(id);

    if (ntOptional.isPresent()) {

        List<rity> rities = rityRepository.findByntDomain(ntOptional.get());
        return rities.stream()
                     .map(SrityDTO::new)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else {    
        throw new Exception(" not exist.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume, that you have typo in your class names, since in java all [class names should have capitalized at least first letter](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Your query could look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW example.SrityDTO(r.id, r.name) FROM Rity r JOIN r.main m WHERE m.id = :domainId")
List<SrityDTO> getByCommonColumn(@Param("domainId") int id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply also please let me know since I am using spring boot with JPA so for this query from where I will get createQuery method since as per my knowledge we use to get this in case of entity manager but in spring boot application we do not have entity manger interface separately created

Comment: I edited my answer, also you can create custom repository and inject `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;`